# Drupal email users

Tags: email, drupal, cck

I'm using Drupal 6.16:  When a user creates an account on my site I have them select a category (ie children, youth, adult, etc).  This is done with the select list box using the content_profile module.  I have a content type that posts an announcement. In this content type is a check box that says 'email group'.  Right now it does nothing, but what I would like for it to do is e-mail all the users that are associated with the group they chose when signing up for their account.  If this will require extra code please be specific as I am not a strong php programmer.

Thanks for the help!!
msindle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some module that do it exactly, but I don't think so.
I would have done it using few building blocks:

- Retrieve the list of emails using Views - define a view that gives you the addresses according to a given group argument.
- Use Rules module that will send an email notification after node is created.
- Combine the two (this is the hard part) - insert the values from the view as the recipients for the email. You might be able to do it using PHP inside the Rule definition, plus view execution.

Try to accomplish it, and if you get into troubles, you are welcome to contact me via shushu.i@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I would try http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions module + http://drupal.org/project/messaging module. You can set preferences for automatic subscribing to content type. Maybe Rules module can subscribe users automatically after creating or updating content_profile. Or maybe Rules can flag users after creating or updating content_profile and Subscription module could autosubscribe flagged users.